# How do I copy a stacktrace out of the debugger in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

How do I copy a stacktrace out of the debugger in Pharo?

I know there's the Debug.log file somewhere near the image, but I'm far too lazy to navigate out of Pharo, to the file system, find the folder, and browse through a gigantic text file if there's a stack trace right in front of me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know a way, but it is not the best. When you are inside the debugger, right click -> "mail out bug report" and there you can copy/paste the stacktrace heheheh

Another option is to bring ctrl + click in order to bring the other menu, and select the option "copy text"

cheers

Comment: +1 The bug report is very detailed. It includes more than a list methods on the stack. It shows the arguments for each call and the receiver instance variables.

Comment: by now you can now simply right-click on the debugger and do a "copy to clipboard"

Comment: or even newer, serialize the stack as fuel file and then simply import it into a similar image to inspect it again.

Answer (score 0):

In Pharo 5, there is a ***Copy to clipboard*** menu entry in the overflow menu of the debugger. See the screenshot:

[image: How to copy stacktrace to clipboard in Pharo 5]