# Pharo Goferit results in MessageNotUnderstood: FileList

Tags: centos, pharo

I just installed Pharo5.0 and attempting to go through
"Pharo by Example".

When I get to the BouncingAtomsMorph I apply the "Gofer it"
fetch provided by MartinW at [Error Unknown variable:BouncingAtomsMorph openInWorld please correct or cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197480/error-unknown-variablebouncingatomsmorph-openinworld-please-correct-or-cancel)

This results in a MessageNotUnderstood: FileList class>>registerFileReader:

```
AnimatedImageMorph class  initialize  [:cl | cl registerFileReader: self ]
BlockClosure cull:
SystemDicdtionary(Dictionary) at:ifPresent:
AnimatedImageMorph class initialize
MCMethodDefinition postloadOver:
MCPackageLoader basicLoadDefinitions ....
```

This list can't be copied by swiping with a mouse, so please excuse typos. (Is there any way to get this list in text format?)

Is Pharo5.0 a stable release? I didn't notice any install problems.

My system is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511

Comment: Regarding your "How do i copy the stacktrace?" question. I added an updated answer to a previous question asking about it: [How do I copy a stacktrace out of the debugger in Pharo?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41084369/2012262)

Answer (score 2):

Pharo 5 is a stable release, but the `MorphExamplesAndDemos` package is no longer updated for the use in Pharo 5.

On the bright side, the error you report is not related to `BouncingAtomsMorph` but to another example in the package. If the debugger window appears, you can click on ***Abandon*** and still use the `BouncingAtomMorph` by doing:

```
BouncingAtomsMorph new openInWorld
```

Probably someone should fix the package, or we should stop mentioning it in Pharo documentation..

Comment: Sorry about the question. I'm just starting with Pharo and the first "non-trivial" attempt results in errors! Discouraging as well as wondering about the stability of the package.  I realize that documentation seems to take a backseat in any software development, but intro tutorial matters should provide a certain degree of confidence to newcomers. Perhaps when I get better I will go back and fix some of these shortcomings that allow a newcomer to have a better experience. And I *do* hope that Pharo is a great product! :) :)

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry about :) I just checked, and the [newest version of Pharo by example](http://files.pharo.org/books/) does no longer mention the `BouncingAtomsMorph`. It is a really old (but charming)  example and I guess the reason it was moved out of the official Pharo distribution and rescued to an external package was that it was no longer updated.